# Open Rings-First Abstract Algebra Text

Tags: textbooks, abstract-algebra

Building off my own experience and the responses to "[Rings before groups in abstract algebra?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/rings-before-groups-in-abstract-algebra)" I've decided to teach Abstract Algebra using a rings-first approach. However the various texts mentioned in that post are not available for free to students. Our department tries to use open texts as much as possible.

> Does anyone know of and/or recommend an open text for Abstract Algebra that uses a rings-first approach?

(Note: In the past, when taking a groups-first approach, I was very happy with [Judson's text](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/aata.html). However, the path to rings is a bit long in that text.)

Comment: What is the topology for the space of textbooks ? First I need to know this to help.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.csun.edu/~asethura/GIAAFILES/GIAAV1.0/GIAAV1.0.pdf

"A Gentle Introduction to Abstract Algebra"

this text is pretty good (I used it in my undergraduate algebra course), starts with rings, and uses a distribution license similar to that of linux